Error al ejecutar la función numpy full() "could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (3,2)"
Utilizo la función np.full() para hacer una transformación, sumar las columnas (y las filas) de un dataframe, y construir un array de las mismas dimensiones que el dataframe original con el resultado de la suma.

import numpy as np

tacono = pd.DataFrame(
  np.array([[1954, 837],[920, 2475],[2831, 2983]]),
  index = ["primaria", "secundaria", "universitaria"],
  columns = ["mañana", "noche"]
)
tacono.columns.name = "horario"
tacono.index.name = "nivel_educativo"

#Transformación partiendo de las filas del DataFrame
rsum = np.full(tacono.shape, tacono.sum(axis=1)).T


Llegamos a este error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\...\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 330, in full
    multiarray.copyto(a, fill_value, casting='unsafe')
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (3,2)


Sin embargo, si hacemos la transformación partiendo de las columnas no hay error:
csum = np.full(tacono.shape, tacono.sum(axis=0))
csum


array([[5705, 6295],
       [5705, 6295],
       [5705, 6295]], dtype=int64)


El problema tal como el error muestra es que intentas rellenar un array de 2 columnas usando un array plano de tres elementos. Para usar numpy.full tendrías que proporcionarle un array de 3x1:
tacono.sum(axis=1).to_numpy().reshape(tacono.shape[0], 1)

pero es mucho más simple invertir las dimensiones requeridas y luego simplemente trasponerlo:
>>> np.full(tacono.shape[::-1], tacono.sum(axis=1)).T

array([[2791, 2791],
       [3395, 3395],
       [5814, 5814]])

